# adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() crashes for listview inside fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

i have one arraylist inside onCreateView() of fragment which contains the data to be updated inside listview, i am using interface callback to update the data from another activity as follow:

```
listUpdatable.update(nameStr,otpStr,timeStr);
```

my update method inside the fragment is as follow:

```
   @Override
public void update(String name, String time, String otp) {
    SentMessageModel message = new SentMessageModel();
    message.setOtp(otp);
    message.setName(name);
    message.setTime(time);
    messages.add(0, message);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The app carashes on calling update method is showing the NPE on arraylist.
   What should i do?

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sent_message_history, container, false);
    ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.sent_message_listView);
    emptyText = view.findViewById(R.id.empty_text);
    messages = new ArrayList<>();
    databaseCodeForAll(); // fetches the content of messages arraylist from  sqlite
    adapter = new SentMessageAdapter(getContext(), messages);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The code is inside onCreateView().

Comment: Show more code.

Comment: which portion of code u want to see?

Comment: How you setting up messages array and initialize your array.

Comment: It's hard to say since there are only pieces of code here, but you are probably calling `update()` before the list has been initialized.